# ¿Porqué el valor de esta variable siempre da cero?

Tags: c#, array, lógica

El postulado de problema dice así:

> 3. Utilizando un arreglo llamado COMPRAS, ingresar el total de las compras efectuadas (por cada uno) de un grupo 10 trabajadores.  Buscar y mostrar en pantalla la mayor y menor compra.

Este es mi código:

```
using System;
namespace Ejercicio_3___Guía_de_ejercicios_de_vectores
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declaración del arreglo que almacenará el valor total de las compras realizadas:
        double[] COMPRAS = new double[10];
        int Contador = 1; //Variable "muletilla" para facilitar el conteo
        double M = 0, m = COMPRAS[0]; /*M = Variable que va a almacenar el valor del arreglo con mayor monto.
        m = Variable que va a almacenar el valor del arreglo con mayor monto. Inicializada en primer posición del vector 
        porque si se arranca desde cero, según la lógica de este programa, no va a cambiar de valor ya que cero es el mínimo valor sin
        tomar en cuenta negativos*/

        //Ciclo de recopilación de datos:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de la compra " + Contador + " : \n");
            COMPRAS[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Contador++;
        }
        //Ciclo de lectura y evaluación lógica de datos para obtener el monto mayor de compras.
        for (int i =0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(M > COMPRAS[i])
            {
                M = M + 0;
            }
            else
            {
                M = COMPRAS[i];
            }
        }
        //Ciclo de lectura y evaluación lógica de datos para obtener el monto menor de compras.
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(m > COMPRAS[i])
            {
                m = COMPRAS[i];
            }
        }
        //Impresión de resultados
        Console.WriteLine("Monto de mayor compra: $" + M);
        Console.WriteLine("Monto de menor compra: $" + m);
    }

}
```

}

Pero el valor de m siempre me termina dando cero y no entiendo porqué.

Comment: ¿Debería entonces de borrarla para evitar infringir normas comunitarias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como inicializaste `M` con un valor pequeño para que el primer registro se tome como el mayor, `m` debes inicializarlo con un valor absurdamente grande para que se tome el primer registro como el menor.

```
double m = Double.MaxValue;
```

En el código anterior `m` toma el valor más grande que se le puede asignar a una variable de tipo `double`. En la primer comparación que se haga, `m` va a tomar el valor que haya ingresado el usuario y de ahí en más las comparaciones se realizan sobre lo que ingresa el usuario.

Otra forma de hacerlo, que creo es la que querés, es asignarle el valor del primer elemento del arreglo a `m` luego de que el usuario ingrese los valores.

```
//Ciclo de recopilación de datos:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de la compra " + Contador + " : \n");
        COMPRAS[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Contador++;
    }

m = COMPRAS[0];
```